# using hta with frameset - drop image does not work

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, frames, hta

I am working with framesets in a local hta (HTML-Application) in internet explorer 10+.
I want to drop files (images) to a dropzone (div or body).
- hta without frames works
- htm with and without frames works (all browsers)
- hta with frames show the image in the frame

index.hta:

```
<frameset cols="40%,60%" >
  <frame src="start1.htm" name="start1" application="yes" >
  <frame src="start2.htm" name="start2" application="yes" >
</frameset>
```

start1.htm

```
<html>
<body ondragstart="return false;">
<div id="dropspot" style="border: 1px dashed #555; height: 200px">
</div>

function init() 
{
  // Set the drop-event handlers.
  var dropArea = document.getElementById("dropspot");
  dropArea.addEventListener("drop", dropHandler, false);
  dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", doNothing, false);
}
function dropHandler(event)
{
  // Use our doNothing() function to prevent default processing. 
  doNothing(event);
  // Get the file(s) that are dropped.
  var filelist =  event.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!filelist) return;  // if null, exit now
  var filecount = filelist.length;  // get number of dropped files
  if (filecount > 0) 
  {
      alert("it works");
  } 
}
// Prevents the event from continuing so our handlers can process the event.
function doNothing(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}
init();
```

In hta the dropHandler() is not called.
Any ideas?
THX armin

Comment: The modern event handling model can be used in IE9+ modes only (HTML5 DTD and `x-ua-compatible` with content IE>8. However, the problem is, that HTML5 doesn't support `frameset` and `frame`s. I'd suggest you to remove the frameset, and use `iframe`s instead.

Comment: to remove this frameset ist not really easy - it is an older and big local app and I have not the time to do this

Comment: With IE10+ it works, but hta starts with mshta.exe. 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
and mshta.exe runs with IE11 on my machine - all the other HTML5 stuff is activ - the only problem is hta + frameset + ondrop